# How can I like and retwweet with cefsharp?

Tags: twitter, cefsharp

I am trying to send a like and a retweet command to a twitter page, with cefsharp, but my tries don't work any more until now.

The like button has  'ProfileTweet-actionButton js-actionButton js-actionFavorite' as button class name.
The tweet buutton has 'ProfileTweet-actionButton  js-actionButton js-actionRetweet' as classname : that opens a window with a button having  'EdgeButton EdgeButton--primary retweet-action' as class name.

```
string click = "document.getElementsByClassName('EdgeButton EdgeButton--primary retweet-action')[0].submit();";      //.button();";     //ProfileTweet-actionButton  js-actionButton js-actionRetweet
Task<JavascriptResponse> response = browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(click);


click = "document.getElementsByClassName('ProfileTweet-actionButton js-actionButton js-actionFavorite')[0].submit();";  //.button();";
response = browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(click);
```

gives a {not yet computed} Task.result, and button() instead of submit() methods give the same result.
Perhaps the do-undo buttons add a layer of something, to click on them ?

Tx a lot for your tips/ideas, in all cases.

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript

Comment: Tx for your help. I already wrote some code, to check that the page was totally loaded, but my code has surely something wrong with that ...

Comment: Edit your question to show this code.  You also should await the EvaluateScriptAsync calls